# 3-manifold with boundary containing a projective plane

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, 3-manifolds

Let $M$ be a compact $3$-manifold such that no component of $\partial M$ is $S^2$ and one component $F$ of $\partial M$ is the projective plane.

If $i_*:\pi_1(F) \to \pi_1(M)$ is an isomorphism, can we prove that $M$ is homeomorphic to $F \times [0,1]$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the result follows from a theorem of [Livesay](https://doi.org/10.2307/1970543) and the Poincaré Conjecture that if $M$ is a compact connected non-orientable 3-manifold with $\pi_1(M)$ finite, then $M$ is homeomorphic to $P^2\times I$ minus a collection of disjoint open 3-balls.

---

The first answer to the original question that I wrote here was flawed. Here is a corrected version, thanks to the comments below.

First note that $M$ is non-orientable since it contains a 2-sided projective plane. Let $N$ be the orientation double cover of $M$, and let $p:N\to M$ be the covering map. Then $N$ is simply-connected since $\pi_1(M)\cong\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$.

If some component of $\partial M$ had non-positive Euler characteristic, then the same would be true of some component of $\partial N$, but this cannot happen since $N$ is simply-connected. By assumption, no component of $\partial M$ is a 2-sphere. Hence $\partial M$ is a collection of projective planes. Let $k$ be the number of components of $\partial M$.

By the Poincaré Conjecture, $N$ is homeomorphic to a 3-sphere with the interiors of $k$ disjoint 3-balls removed. Let $q:N\to N$ be the covering transformation, an orientation reversing involution. Now $H_2(N;\mathbb{Q})\cong\mathbb{Q}^{k-1}$ and $H_2(N;\mathbb{Q})$ is generated by any $k-1$ components of $\partial N$. Since $q$ acts on each component of $\partial N$ as an orientation reversing homeomorphism, it follows that the Lefschetz number $\Lambda_q$ is given by
$$\Lambda_q=1-0+(-(k-1))=2-k.$$
But $q$ has no fixed points, so $\Lambda_q=0$ and $k=2$. See [Epstein](https://doi.org/10.1112/plms/s3-11.1.469) for the original (and more general) proof of this step.

Therefore $N$ is homeomorphic to $S^2\times I$, and it follows by Livesay or [Rubinstein](https://doi.org/10.1090/S0002-9939-1976-0420625-3) that $M$ is homeomorphic to $P^2\times I$. The argument I had in mind here involves doubling $N$ along its boundary to get $S^2\times S^1$. The covering map $p$ also extends to the double. Then the [classification](https://doi.org/10.1112/blms/15.5.401) of Seifert fibered spaces covered by $S^2\times\mathbb{R}$ tells us that the only compact quotient of $S^2\times S^1$ which contains a 2-sided projective plane is $P^2\times S^1$. Hence $M$ is homeomorphic to $P^2\times I$.

Comment: The fact that $k=2$ follows from the Lefschetz fixed point theorem. Indeed, since the deck transformation of the covering map has no fixed point, its Lefschetz number must be $0$. By direct calculation, $k=2$. What I do not understand is how to deduce $M=P^2 \times I$ if we know $N=S^2 \times I$?

Comment: It is a theorem of Livesay (1963 Annals of Math., pp. 582-593) that $M=P^2\times I$ if $N=S^2\times I$. A shorter proof was later published by Rubinstein in the 1976 Proceedings of the AMS, pp. 317-320.

Comment: If this new argument is now correct, the comment stating that there is a gap/mistake should probably be deleted or modified to avoid future confusion.

Comment: Surely the bottom line is that the desired result is in fact Epstein's theorem (plus the Poincare conjecture)?  From the MR review of Epstein's paper: "In the second chapter the author shows, surprisingly, that any compact non-orientable 3-manifold with finite fundamental group has to be (modulo the Poincaré conjecture) homeomorphic to $P^2×I$ minus a number of 3-balls".

Comment: Epstein's result is that such a manifold is homotopy equivalent to $P^2\times I$ minus some balls. See the comments on p477 of his paper, where he states that to upgrade to homeomorphism, one needs to prove two conjectures: one is the Poincaré Conjecture, the other is the result of Livesay.

Comment: @JoshHowie: So it is! That will teach me to trust the MR review. Thanks for the explanation.